# importing external jar files

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, javac

I have written a Java code which imports an external jar file. How can I compile and run it on the command-line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Compiling from the command-line:

```
javac -cp path_to_jar1.jar:path_to_jar2.jar Example.java
```

Running:

```
java -cp .:path_to_jar1.jar:path_to_jar2.jar Example
```

For Windows, use `;` as a path-separator (instead of `:`).

Comment: @ khachik Sorry for the late reply ... Thanx a lot for your advice... I marked your answer as correct... thanx again :-)

Comment: I still get an error: if I invoke `java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar  Connect` I get the error that Java cannot find the `Connect` class.

Comment: @Daniele 4 years late; but that would mean the Connect.class file is not being found, did you compile first?