# How to run java project in command line with external imports?

Tags: java, command-line, import

can someone explain me how to run a Java project in command line with external imports, if possible a step by step guide?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421730/importing-external-jar-files

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by external import? Are these just 3rd pary Jar files that you are using? If so when you run the jar command you can specify a path for your external libraries, or better still insert this info into the manifest file.

Comment: yes,i mean 3rd party jar files

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the classpath option of java: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html